# The type of namespace 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore'

Tags: sitecore

Added Sitecore.Logging dll (from nuget) in the project but I still get the error.

It was working fine until I added a log4net dll (as part of some other nuget dependency). After this there was an ambiguous reference error. Then when I tried to specify Sitecore.Logging.LogManager/ Sitecore.Logging.ILog I get the error .

The type of namespace 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore'

Comment: Sitecore version?

Comment: 8.2.3 version it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the newly added log4net dll -> properties -> Aliases-> give a different name like 'log'. This will resolve the ambiguity in the code.

Comment: Ah ok, yes potentially the log4net is coming in via a dependency - I didn't think of that.  In which case @BlueClouds is completely right, you can set an alias on the Assembly Reference in Solution Explorer, which is typically `global`, but can be anything, so using the above example you'd end up with differentiated globally qualified names of `global::log4net.LogManager` (which would be the `Sitecore.Logging.dll` one) and `log::log4net.LogManager` (the `log4net.dll` one)

Answer (score 2):

The `Sitecore.Logging.dll` does not contain classes in the `Sitecore.Logging` namespace, though you may be forgiven for expecting that to be the case - it is certainly the convention.

Opening it up with a decompiler reveals a forked version of log4net hiding in there.

[image: Sitecore.Logging.dll contents]

You are probably looking for the log factory in `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log` in the `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`

Comment: LogManager and ILog is ambiguous as per the compile time error message. the newly added log4net has to be removed for this to work. Both log4net and Sitecore.Logging cannot exist together, right? Also which dll contains namepace in Sitecore.Logging?

Comment: The `Sitecore.Logging.dll` contains all the log4net functionality. There is no need to add a separate `log4net.dll`. Further, there are no classes in the namespace `Sitecore.Logging`

Comment: well ofcourse there is no need. I would not add it either. But a nugetpackage is brining it. And it is there. Now, how to deal with it, is the question infront of me.

Comment: Remove it from your nuGet package file champ